# Decorators: Why am I getting different results? If I'm passing a function with parameters, is @ notation compulsory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

```
def smart_divide(func):
   def inner(a,b):
      print("I am going to divide",a,"and",b)
      if b == 0:
         print("Whoops! cannot divide")
         return
      return func(a,b)
   return inner

@smart_divide
def divide(a,b):
    return a/b
print(divide(10,2))   # prints 5, correct
```

## code snippet 2:

```
def smart_divide(func):
   def inner(a,b):
      print("I am going to divide",a,"and",b)
      if b == 0:
         print("Whoops! cannot divide")
         return
      return func(a,b)
   return inner

def divide(a,b):
    return a/b

print(smart_divide(divide(10,2))) # why is this printing function address ?
```

Answer (score 2):

The second snippet is wrong.

```
@smart_divide
def divide(a,b):
    ...

divide(10,2)
```

Is equivalent to

```
smart_divide(divide)(10, 2)
# Not to smart_divide(divide(10,2))
```

See the difference? `smart_divide` expects a function. You provided it a float. If you then try to call it again you will get the expected error `'float' object is not callable`:

```
 smart_divide(divide(10, 2))(10, 2)
 TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```